# Rails html.erb filetype, difference between <% %> and <%= %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just began digging into Ruby and Ruby on Rails, and I noticed two options for embedding Ruby syntax within .html.erb files:

```
<% #ruby code here %>
```

Or:

```
<%= #ruby code here %>
```

How should I choose one over the other?

Comment: `<%= %>` will output the result, `<% %>` will not.

Comment: Thanks @DaveJohnston. I searched for similar questions based on the syntax, but I didn't see that post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<%=` outputs the result of the Ruby. `<%` just evaluates the Ruby.

```
<p>Hi! How are you? 1 + 1 = <%= 1 + 1 %></p>
```

Will become `<p>Hi! How are you? 1 + 1 = 2</p>`.

```
<p>Hi! How are you? 1 + 1 = <% 1 + 1 %></p>
```

Will become `<p>Hi! How are you? 1 + 1 = </p>`.

`<%` is generally used for flow control, ex. `if/else`. Example:

```
<% if model.nil? %>
  <%= render 'new_model_form' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'detail_view' %>
<% end %>
```

Read more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Nice concise answer with examples. Much appreciated.

Comment: Well said.  It might help only to add that <% is generally used for flow control like if/else, iterators, etc

Answer (score 1):

<%= renders, <% does not.